# Message sent to deallocated instance, when working with an NSManagedObject indirectly

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, memory, nsmanagedobject

I have this code that is giving me a headache:

/ original code removed, see current version below /

The message I receive:

`*** -[__NSDate class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x69fa350`

**EDIT 3:**

To test it, I have moved everything into one method, and verified that it still produces the same error.
This is a splitView iPad app. A `voiceMemo` object is passed by the left-side table view controller upon selection. The right side view has a tableView on its own, this is where I am loading the reminders.

What happens, is this:
Initially, everything loads correctly. Without any `reminder` data in my database, I can select any entry, it loads correctly. I can delete them, modify them, etc.
I can select an entry with `reminder` data, and it loads correctly. The table view in the detail view is correctly populated with data. However, trying to modify a `reminder`, the program crashes: message sent to deallocated instance.
Without trying to modify any data, the program crashes if I try to load another entry WITH `reminder` data.
I can delete entries which have no `reminder` from the (left side) main table view, but when trying to delete one *with* `reminder` data, it crashes (on the `save` method). The next time I start the program, the entry is deleted, though.

The database and the custom classes are shared with the iPhone version, which works correctly.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /* only relevant parts posted */

    // Left-side label (title)

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]     
        initWithKey:@"DBreminderDate" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSMutableArray *sortedReminders = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
        [voiceMemo.reminders allObjects]];

    [sortedReminders sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    self.remindersArray = sortedReminders;    

    AKReminder *reminder = [remindersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = reminder.DBreminderTitle;

    if ([cell.textLabel.text length] == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Reminder";
    }

    // Right-side label (date)

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [format setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];
    NSDate *reminderSetTo = reminder.DBreminderDate;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [format     
        stringFromDate:reminderSetTo]]; // breaks here

    return cell;
}
```

My data model:

[image: Core Data data model]

Comment: Seems the problem is on a NSDate object... I can't see it on your code. Maybe it's somewhere else...

Comment: @Macmade That's why I'm puzled.. This line of code invokes the [NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] method, and that's where it breaks.

Comment: Since you state the problem is with a deallocated `NSDate` instance, I suspect it has something to do with your Core Data model. The `-sortUsingDescriptors` method is trying to access the object at keypath `DBreminderDate`, based on the descriptor, which seems to be have been deallocated.

Comment: @Deepak You seem to be right, the problem happens elsewhere as well, when trying to work with the objects. I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I can't tell you why but I suppose if you do `reminderSetTo = [[reminder.DBreminderDate copy] autorelease];` in the last piece of code, it might work there.

Comment: First off, why are you allocating and initializing an empty date in the second part of the code, then immediately overriding it? This leaks memory (it should be `NSDate *reminderSetTo = reminder.DBReminderDate;`, or). And second, I agree with Deepak. Can you post a screenshot of your Core Data model maybe? Also, where is the `reminder` object declared? That code could certainly be relevant...

Comment: @Itai Ferber See my edit above. About memory: I usually allocate object that way, so I can release them myself, when they're no longer needed. That release was not included in the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
    initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:1];
```

looks strange to me.
Do you mean:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
    initWithObjects:sortDescriptor count:1];
```

?

Any object you add to an NSArray should derive from NSObject; &sortDescriptor does not (is the address in memory of a pointer to sortDescriptor).
This could be causing an improper attempt to deallocate &sortDescriptor instead of sortDescriptor when sortDescriptors is deallocated...

Comment: This seems to be a problem to me. Try using `NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];` and remove the release statement further down.

Comment: Yes, very good point! I have edited the code (see above), but the issue still persist.